# Impute NaN Values based on mean by catégories

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, nan, missing-data

I am struggling with something that might seem simple:
I want to replace `NaN`by the mean of the value for the `Disease`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Disease' : [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'Value1' : [3, 1, 2, 4, np.nan], 
                   'Value2' : [13, 21, np.nan, 16, 87], 'Value3' : [np.nan, 5, 11, 54, np.nan]})
```

[image: My data with NaN]

I want to replace the `NaN`value by these:

```
df.groupby(by='Disease').mean()
```

[image]

I tried to loop through the dataframe but I am stuck when I try to assign the new value in the original dataframe.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: `df.fillna(df.groupby('Disease').transform('mean'))` : transform mean and then fillna

Comment: Although I searched for a while, I could not find the aforementioned answer. Sorry for the repost and thank you for your answer.